# MYSQL Replace number values

Tags: mysql, replace

I've got a table in my database with id's and I'm tryning to replace them with a new id's. Example:

```
|  id |
------
|  1  |
|  1  |
|  1  |
| 14  |
| 14  |
|  6  |
|  6  |
|  6  |
```

I want to replace all 1 with 25, 14 with 18, 6 with 15 etc. But when i run:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, '1', '25')
```

It changes all 1 to 25 and also 14 to 254. How to do this right?

Comment: Why do you want to replace id values from 1 to 25 and 14 to 18 etc..? and it is not best practice to have duplicate id's in your table which should be a primary key column..

Comment: It's just an example. I want to replace old category id to a new one to all my posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a where condition after update statement.

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, '1', '25')
where id = 1
```

If `your_field` is id; Then you can use;

```
UPDATE your_table
SET id = REPLACE(id, '1', '25')
where id = 1
```

Comment: Don't you just want to "UPDATE your_table set id = 25 where id = 1"?